# public transport routing with OSM

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, graphhopper

is it possible "public transport routing" with OSM?
Using osmDroid, Graphhopper or other Libs.

I build a navigation app and i wanna navigat with car, bike, foot and public transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the routing engine you want to use. GraphHopper doesn't support public transport routing. But according to the [list of OSM online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) public transportation is supported by OpenTripPlanner, TripGo and Mapzen Turn-by-Turn.